# What happens to the reputation when a question is migrated?

Tags: support, reputation, migration

My question was migrated from the English Stack Exchange to the History of Science and Math Stack Exchange.

My question is, does the reputation I gained while it was on the English S.E stay on my English S.E and also goes onto the History of Science and Math SE, or does it remove itself and migrate itself to the History of Science and Math SE, or something else?

(To shorten the sentence up, what happens to the reputation gained on a migrated question? Where does it go?)

I am curious about this because I just joined the History of Science and Math SE for my migrated question, but I gained more than 100 reputation (the associated bonus).

I'd like to know where the extra 119 reputation came from.

EDIT: My question is different because I'm wondering where the 119 extra reputation (other than the 100 rep from the associated bonus) came from.

Comment: Re your edit, that's exactly what the dupe target *does* explain. It's not talking about association bonus at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't quite understand what you mean. My question is asking where the extra reputation came from, because my thinking was that it could have come from the migrated question. It couldn't have come from the associated bonus, because it is more than 100 rep.

Comment: You have 24 upvotes and one downvote. 24x5=120-1=119.

Comment: @Catija Yes. So does that mean migrated questions that have upvotes make it so that the asker receives the upvotes on both sites?

Comment: Oh, I see where the confusion is coming in... no, you lose the reputation on ELU... the question will eventually be deleted there, it won't exist soon, so you don't get the reputation any more. It's still active on ELU, so you have the rep right now but you'll eventually lose it. But, as long as the question is kept on HSM, you'll keep the reputation there.

Comment: @Catija Ah yes that was the answer I was looking for. Because the duplicate question said that I would lose the rep, but I didn't, so I got confused.

Answer (score 1):

Reputation gained upon posts is site specific.

> To shorten the sentence up, what happens to the reputation gained on a migrated question?

It's reset to zero, as soon your question is migrated.

> Where does it go?

To the fairies realm.

---

> I am curious about this because I just joined the History of Science and Math SE for my migrated question, but I gained more than 100 reputation (the associated bonus).

The site association bonus is a completely different thing, and independent of the actually migrated post.

Comment: I know about the associated bonus, but what I'm saying is that when I came onto the History of Science and Math SE I got more than 100 reputation. So I was wondering if it came from the question or not.